# Area 51 Proposal: Finance (including Corporate, Public Finance)

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/28304/why-do-banks-offer-tender-these-loans-at-these-low-rates) and Chris W. Rea's comment motivated me to create

[Finance (including Behavioural, Corporate, Public Finance)](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/65253/finance-including-corporate-public-finance?referrer=6QElsEDFZNHQUFd8NAy7ig2)

Please allow me to advert to it here and advise me if this affronts or afflicts anyone and forgive me.

It's intended to be more general and catholic, but equally as instructive and useful, as the present finance websites. Moreover, I aspire for it to welcome, appertain to, and assist with subjects and topics esteemed "off-topic" on the current finance websites, and thus to complete any lacunae or rifts in content and coverage.

Please feel free to contribute, support, and opine on it. I will be grateful for your contributions and support.

Comment: I hope it works out.  There are many questions a year that we have to close here, but would be good there.  I think you should feel encouraged to promote it in your comments on this site.

Comment: I know this isn't english.SE, but would someone kindly explain to me the use of the word *catholic* in the question?

Comment: The topic proposed looks quite different from money.se ... of course there may be a small overlap, but that happens all the times and we can figure out how to move question around between this and the new site whenever it comes up ...

Comment: Both startups and economics failed. Not to be a downer, but the first step is 40 typical questions and as of now, there are none. Even the OP hasn't loaded any.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer I had to look it up, too. Google reports back one definition is: *"adjective
1. (esp. of a person's tastes) including a wide variety of things; all-embracing. synonyms: universal, diverse, diversified, wide, broad, broad-based, eclectic, liberal, latitudinarian"*

Comment: @MrChrister: Thank you for your support. Would there be any closed questions germane to that proposal? I'll be happy to post it there.

Comment: @JoeTaxPayer: Please forgive me for any inconvenience. Yes, Chris W. Rea is right.

Comment: No problem, I was raised Catholic, and 12 years of Catholic school. I never heard the word used as an adjective in that context. Chris and I learned something, and I thank you.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer: Wonderful to know! You are most welcome. I thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Is it an 'overflow' to Money.SE or will it attract its own questions? i.e. it should have a following that keeps the site active and Money will actually get questions deemed 'off-topic, this is about personal finance.'

The idea is fine, but keep in mind the other sites that have already failed due to lack of support, e.g. the economics site.

Keep in mind, it's taken this stack a long time to graduate. I don't expect a splinter group from this site can make it.