# How do I find questions closed because it was averred as "off-topic"?

Tags: support

I'm trying to find such questions so that they can be promoted and resolved in my new Area 51 proposal: [Area 51 Proposal: Finance (including Corporate, Public Finance)](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1899/area-51-proposal-finance-including-corporate-public-finance).

Comment: http://data.stackexchange.com/money/queries - are you good with queries?  Maybe you can figure it out.  I am looking through queries with "off topic" and not seeing what you are asking for, but maybe.

Answer (score 2):

Questions that are closed here as *off-topic* have a limited life span. Eventually, they get deleted, either by a moderator performing a cleanup, or when a sufficient number of high-rep users vote to delete each such question.

Consequently, most of the off-topic questions you're likely to find here will be more recent ones that haven't yet been purged in either of those two ways. Many hundreds more have already been deleted.

If you want to find closed but not yet deleted questions, you can look at this query: ["closed:1"](https://money.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&pagesize=50&q=closed:1). However, the results aren't limited to questions that were closed for reason of being off-topic. Except for those labeled "[duplicate]" in the title, you'll need to look click through each individually to find out the more detailed close reason.

Comment: Chris W Rea: High rep users can also see questions that were recently deleted. May be someone in se can help get complete list of such questions.

Comment: @Dheer But are you aware of a way to *search* for those deleted questions? There's the rub.

Comment: Nope. Since we can see deleted for last 30 days, I am guessing they are never fully deleted and someone at StackExchange may be able to help with a query or a one time data dump.